# Eclipse Expressions view with PyDev - expand objects

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I use Eclipse and PyDev for my work.

I have seen elsewhere (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/expressions/ref-expressions_view.htm) that it is possible to have the expressions view have "expandable" objects, so that one can "open" the result of an expression to see the fields of that object.

The Variables view supports this, which is VERY useful for debugging. For some reason though, that doesn't apply to the Expressions view... when there are lots of elements (say, in a list), the Variables view is hard to browse... so having something like `my_list[10241]` in the Expressions view could bring up a specific element of that list without having to scroll down 10241 elements in the Variables view (if even possible, most of the times I tried something like this, the number of shown elements is set to 500 anyway) to expand that element's fields.

Does anyone know about this? Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyDev does not have that feature. Please create a feature request for that.

Comment: There already exists a feature request, ID 2947729... I added a comment there with a link to this page.